# APATAR - MySQL Data Integration to Salesforce

Tags: custom-object, bulk-api

We are trying to migrate data from MySql to Salesforce through APATAR. I created transformation and the complete data (For Example:1,00,000 Records) was available up to transformation level, But in Salesforce only 14,101 records got inserted. Is that due to some configuration problem or that is the limitation possible through APATAR?

Note:

For Salesforce I even Selected **"Use Bulk API"** option.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with APATAR itself, but the general idea of syncing data between mysql and salesforce is a task I'm way too familiar with.

I suspect strongly that the APATAR software has an error log, in which you'll find that while 14,000 some odd records were inserted, all of them were tried. Data validation issues can prevent individual records from being inserted. Specifically, things to watch out for include:

1. String fields in Mysql exceeding 256 characters, being mapped to text fields in salesforce.
2. Calculated External id's that evaluate to pre-existing records in salesforce
3. Inserting when you need to be *upserting*.
4. API limits. This one is a strong contender for issues. If, for instance, your software is configured to send 200 records per bulk api call, you'll hit your 3000 api call limit relatively quickly. Throw in a few errors and this could be the only (major) issue you're facing. Checkout this page for more info on the bulk api limits: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm

Comment: I know this is not the question, but I am trying to learn the sync between mysql and salesforce, I havent found much docs aside from the trailhead tutorial of lighting connect, and a bunch of external system. Do you know or could you please recommend me a good tutoriall to achieve this for instance if the database is in godaddy, thanks